# Imagemagick: After centering image, move it left by 50px

Tags: image-processing, imagemagick, imagemagick-convert

I am currently centering an image on a white background like below:

```
... -gravity center -background white -extent 400x400 ...
```

I find that after centering, I need to move the image (~250x250, can vary slightly) to the left of the center by 50px. How can I achieve this?

I tried using `-geometry` after `-gravity center` but that doesn't work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try

```
convert ... -gravity center -background white -extent 400x400+50+0 ...
```

Where the ImageMagick documentation talks about "geometry" in this context, it's talking about the "geometry string" associated with the "-extent" option, not about a "-geometry" option.